# javafx To have a scroll method of Panel in the scrollPanel setPannable (true) does not work

Tags: javafx, jscrollpane

I put a scalable pane in the scrollpanel then scroll way after his bigger scrollpanel setPannable (true) method does not work, I don't know how to solve, hope to get help

```
public class CreateAdvancedStage extends Application {
private void init(Stage primaryStage) {
    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
    root.setPrefSize(200, 220);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    ScrollPane scrolPanel = new ScrollPane();
    scrolPanel.setPannable(true);//it do not work
    scrolPanel.setContent(getCenterPane());
    root.setCenter(scrolPanel);

}
Pane panel;
int tag = 10;
public Pane getCenterPane() {
    panel = new Pane();
    panel.setStyle("-fx-background-color:red");
    panel.setPrefSize(100, 100);
    panel.setOnScroll(new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ScrollEvent t) {
            System.out.println("OnScroll");
            //this to set panSize
            if (panel != null) {
                panel.setPrefSize(100 + tag, 100 + tag);
                tag++;
            }
        }
    });
    return panel;
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    init(primaryStage);
    primaryStage.show();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Comment: You can be in redPanel scroll the mouse, appear when the Size is greater than the scrollPanel redPanel ScrollBar then try to drag redPanel，it do not work!

Comment: This works as expected for me. Can you edit your question and make it clearer what you are expecting and how the observed behavior differs from that? (Please consider using [Google translate](https://translate.google.com/) or something similar if translating to English is preventing you from making things clearer.)

Comment: I place a size that can changed by the mouse scroll  pane   in a scrollPane, then I want both  drag this pane location in SrollPanel  and Scroll the mouse to change this pane size，is clear?